# Dynamically populate AJAX hovermenu when hovering

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, user-controls, dynamically-generated

I need to be able to populate a hovermenu when hovering over it, instead of populating a whole gridview of hovermenu data when loading the page.  In other words, I need to populate them "on the fly."

I've put the contents of the popup in Web User Control with example text.  So I need to populate this User Control when hovering over a GridView Row.

Here's the .aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PopupPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modal" style="display: none;">
    <g3:OrderDetailsPopup ID="OrderPopup" runat="server"></g3:OrderDetailsPopup>
</asp:Panel>

<ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="PopupPanel" PopupControlID="PopupPanel" PopupPosition="Top" PopDelay="0"/>
```

The contents of the User Control "OderDetailsPopup":

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="OrderDetailsPopup.ascx.vb" Inherits="UserControls_OrderDetailsPopup" %>

<asp:Panel ID="PopupPanel" runat="server">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Order Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server">LABELBABEL</asp:Label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And the old code behind for the .aspx page (I was just populating when the page Data Bound.  The GridView 'gvOrderDetails' was on the page, instead of in the User Control above.  I removed it from both to simplify this example):

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim hoverMenu As HoverMenuExtender = e.Row.FindControl("HoverPopupExtender")
        e.Row.ID = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()
        hoverMenu.TargetControlID = e.Row.ID
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim detailsGrid As GridView = e.Row.Cells(5).FindControl("gvOrderDetails")
        detailsGrid.DataSource = New G3.Entity.TaskDetails().GetDetailsByOrder(CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("travelOrderID"))
        detailsGrid.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

To elaborate, my hovermenu was working fine before, but it was taking a very long time to load a page of 300 rows, and within each row was a popup hovermenu with it's own data.  So the goals here are:

- Re-usability of the popup code in a User Control
- Popuplate the hovermenus on-the-fly.

Comment: Basically, we just decided to do a DB call when the User Control loads.  /shrug

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we decided to simply do a DB call when the User Control loads..
This *vastly* improved page-load time. And pretty much solved the problem.

```
Public Function RenderMe(OrderID As Integer) As String
    Dim stringBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    If ID > 0 Then
        ViewModel = New VM()
        ViewModel.ID = ID
        ViewModel.Fill()
        OrderDetails.DataSource = ViewModel.T
        DataBind()
        Dim stringWriter As StringWriter = New StringWriter(stringBuilder)
        Dim writer As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
        Render(writer)
    End If
    Return stringBuilder.ToString()
End Function
```